# Android-ScalableVideoView is not repeating

Tags: android, android-videoview, samsung-mobile, android-video-player

I'm using [Android-ScalableVideoView](https://github.com/yqritc/Android-ScalableVideoView) to show a 10s video in a `RelativeLayout` from a [URL](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/29rrnh8ph8v16t7/creed.mp4?dl=0) repeatedly:

```
<com.yqritc.scalablevideoview.ScalableVideoView
                android:id="@+id/vv_mini_trailer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/mini_trailer_height" />
```

And code:

```
@Bind(R.id.vv_mini_trailer) ScalableVideoView vvMiniTrailer;

        try {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(filme.getUrlVideo());
        vvMiniTrailer.setDataSource(this, uri);
        vvMiniTrailer.setScalableType(ScalableType.CENTER_CROP);
        vvMiniTrailer.prepareAsync(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                vvMiniTrailer.setLooping(true);
                vvMiniTrailer.start();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.e("Erro ao executar o mini-trailer " + e.toString());
    }
```

**Problem:**
Running the app in a Samsung Galaxy Note 3, the video is playing only for the first time. Running in a Moto G it's all good. Any ideas?

Comment: "Please note that..." what?  Did you mean to cut off that sentence?

Comment: @db_brad sorry about that! Corrected